# stuccy.com mirroring Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

[stuccy.com](http://stuccy.com/) seems to mirror the complete Stack Overflow site, even with the logo. This violates at least the [trademark guidance](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) rules.

I found it via google.de on page 2 of the search results (position 18).

Comment: It doesn't look like it scrapes at all, posts are instantly visible.  Looks like a proxy that forwards directly to the SO site.  The site is owned by [this company](http://turncommerce.com/), their office is 1.5 miles away from the SE office in Denver.  Hmm.

Answer (score 5):

I have reported this via the [official procedure for scrapers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do).

Just mentioning it here on Meta so that people can search for it to find out whether it has already been reported.